# Need to know whether combinational

Tags: vhdl

I have written a code for counting number of 1s in a given 4-bit `std_logic_vector` and output has to be displayed in 2-bit vector. I have written the code something like this:

```
count <= A + "01" when input(0) = '1' else A;
A     <= B + "01" when input(1) = '1' else B;
B     <= C + "01" when input(2) = '1' else C;
C     <=     "01" when input(3) = '1' else "00";
```

The code worked well but I want to know whether the code  purely combinatorial and synthesizable because I am doubting whether '+' operator is combinatorial or not. 
In my opinion '+' operator is combinatorial because it is implemented using full adder or half adder circuits. Is '+' restricted to integer and real valued operands in combinatorial circuits?

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator is combinatorial and synthesizable.  The `+` can operate
directly on `integer` and `real`, and for operation on `std_logic_vector` you
need to use a package in order to include the necessary functions.  From you code it looks like you have used:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Even with the name, this is a non-IEEE standard package, and the alternative
IEEE standard package is `ieee.numeric_std`.

Note that based on your code, it looks like you are using a 2-bit vector to
count the number of 1's in a 4-bit vector, so if all 4 bits are 1's, the 2-bit
vector will overflow and show the value 0.

An alternative implementation for counting 1's is to make a function that uses
the `ieee.numeric_std` package, and with result length of 3 bits, this may look
like:

```
function cnt_1s(slv : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
  variable res_v : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
  res_v := (others => '0');
  for idx in slv'range loop
    if slv(idx) = '1' then
      res_v := std_logic_vector(unsigned(res_v) + 1);
    end if;
  end loop;
  return res_v;
end function;
```

The function is also synthesizable, since the loop is unrolled to implement the
required amount of hardware, just like the explicit code in the question.  The
function can then be used to make the `count` with:

```
count <= cnt_1s(input);
```